# Populate Entities from Stored Procedure

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, fluent-nhibernate

I am using nHibernate and am trying to populate an entity, which has a subclass of another entity from a stored procedure. I have a RankedListing which contains an Id, a Rank and a Listing

```
public class RankedListing : DomainEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Rank { get; set; }
    public virtual Listing Listing { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling a stored procedure to populate this entity from a `FULLTEXT` search. The stored procedure returns three columns (Id, Rank, and Listing_Id). The code that I'm executing is below.

```
IQuery query = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INHibernateUnitOfWork>().CurrentSession.CreateSQLQuery("exec dbo.usp_SearchListings :Search");
query.SetString("Search", search);

var products = query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(RankedListing))).List<RankedListing>().ToList();
return products;
```

When I execute this, the error that I get back is:

```
Could not find a setter for property 'Listing_Id' in class 'RankedListing'
```

Is there anyway to get this to map the Listing on the RankedListing rather than trying to map it as the column name as a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont know if it's the best way but a custom resulttransformer could do

```
class MyTransformer : IResultTransformer
{
    private ISession _session;
    private Dictionary<int, int> _listingIds = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    public MyTransformer(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }
    public IList TransformList(IList collection)
    {
        var listings = _session.QueryOver<Listing>()
            .WhereRestrictionOn(l => l.Id).IsIn(_listingIds.Values)
            .List().ToDictionary(l => l.Id);
        return collection.Cast<RankedListing>()
            .Select(rl => { rl.Listing = listings[_listingIds[rl.Id]]; return rl; })
            .ToList();
    }

    public object TransformTuple(object[] tuple, string[] aliases)
    {
        var rl = new RankedListing();
        rl.Id = (int)tuple[System.Array.FindIndex(aliases, name => name == "Id")];
        rl.Rank = (int)tuple[System.Array.FindIndex(aliases, name => name == "Rank")];

        _listingIds.Add(rl.Id, (int)tuple[System.Array.FindIndex(aliases, name => name == "Listing_Id")]);

        return rl;
    }
}
```

then use it like:

```
var products = query.SetResultTransformer(new MyTransformer(CurrentSession)).List<RankedListing>();
```

Update: if you want to lazyload the Listings you could also do

```
.Select(rl => { rl.Listing = session.Load<Listing>(_listingIds[rl.Id]); return rl; })
```

Comment: thanks! it gives me an idea. However, I was hoping to avoid extra calls for retrieving each individual listing. I returned all the data that I needed to a DTO and used that in my search results.

Comment: its only adding **1** extra call to the db, which fetches all listings at once.

Comment: oh! I missed that. I didn't actually implement because I had gotten the DTO to work. I will definitely look deeper into this for future needs, I'm sure this isn't the last time in this project where I'll need to use a stored procedure to retrieve data